# Not all fields are rendered in data-ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I have following code to render a menu in MEAN.JS:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="subitem in item.items | orderBy: 'position'" data-ng-if="subitem.shouldRender(authentication.user);" ui-route="{{subitem.uiRoute}}" ng-class="{active: $uiRoute}">
        <a data-ng-href="/#!/{{subitem.link}}" data-ng-bind="subitem.title"></a>
</li>
```

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lFXnnsGAYuYrSufcI1Uk?p=preview)

In Plunker, it is working.

Here, subitem.title works fine, but subitem.link is not rendered.

In Firebug, I am getting this error:

```
Error: uiRoute missing a route or href property on [object HTMLLIElement]
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Can you prepare a jsbin/plnkr?

Comment: Can you check if the {{subitem.link}} is working when placed in the view?

Comment: <a data-ng-bind="subitem.link" data-ng-href="/#!/{{subitem.link}}" ></a> Here I can see subitem.link (in ngBind). But I cannot see in ngHref

Comment: try this ui-route="/{{subitem.uiRoute}}"